# How to download a dynamic file in django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views

I have created a django application that converts txt to csv files. Now, I want to create a view function to download the newly converted csv files. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

How to read the path object in download view?

`views.py`

```
def submit(request):
   # this function uploads txt files.
   # this function converts txt to csv files. For example abcd.txt is converted into abcd0000.csv and abcd0000.csv is stored in /main/temp/ folder.
   path = 'main/temp/converted_file.csv' #(Example)This file is dynamic 
   # context is also present
   context = {'path':path}
   return render(request,'submit.html',context)
```

Now I want to create a download function. For example:

```
def download(request):  
   context = {'path': request.GET.get('path')}
   data = open(path,'r').read()
   resp = HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/x-download')
   resp['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename=path.csv'
   return resp
```

`submit.html`

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>You have successfully converted the file. </p>
<p><a href ="{% url 'download' %} ">Download (Filename)</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To upload a file, you should use a form ? or do you want to upload a file which is available in a root's folder ?

Comment: I want to download the file which is converted. Uploading the file is done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a streamed response like you can see in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/outputting-csv/#streaming-large-csv-files)

In your case it might do something like this with your file;

```py
import csv

from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse

class Echo:
    """An object that implements just the write method of the file-like
    interface.
    """
    def write(self, value):
        """Write the value by returning it, instead of storing in a buffer."""
        return value

def some_streaming_csv_view(request):
    """ A view that streams a large CSV file. """
    data = open(path,'r').readlines()

    pseudo_buffer = Echo()
    writer = csv.writer(pseudo_buffer)
    response = StreamingHttpResponse(
        (writer.writerow(row) for row in data),
        content_type="text/csv"
    )
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'
    return response
```

Add the `GET` param to your URL, because you're already adding it to the context and trying to read it back out;

`<p><a href ="{% url 'download' %}?path={{ path|urlencode }}">Download (Filename)</a></p>`

Comment: In the line  data = open(path,'r').readlines(), the path has to be dynamic. Path is in the submit function. I just want to create a link in the template which downloads the csv file.

Comment: Just add the path to the context on your submit view and then you can pass it to the download view as a get param

Comment: Please give an example, I have edited the code to pass to the download view. Please some more corrections.

Comment: I've added an example of how that'd be done in the template

Comment: I used your code, I can get the path but while downloading, NameError at /download/
name 'path' is not defined in the line: data = open(path,'r').read()

Comment: Correct, it's not. But you can just adapt that method for your view and get the path from the `GET` params.

Comment: I need your suggestion in the improved section of this code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65679286/how-to-request-get-parameters-in-templates-for-a-list-of-filesdjango-zip-file.