# How to request GET parameters in templates for a list of files?(Django Zip File Download Issue)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I want to download all the single or multiple files created by the function by zipping them.

The problem is with templates.
Please suggest properly to pass the GET parameters for a list of files
I got an error :

```
FileNotFoundError at /test/
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '['
```

This is the error for improperly placing the query string that is referring to the list of files.

My views are as follows:

```
def submit(request):
    def file_conversion(input_file,output_file_pattern,chunk_size):
            output_filenames = []
            with open(input_file,"r+") as fin:
    # ignore headers of input files
                for i in range(1):
                    fin.__next__()
            
                reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter=',')
                
                
                for i, chunk in enumerate(chunked(reader, chunk_size)):
                    output_filename = output_file_pattern.format(i)
                    with open(output_filename, 'w', newline='') as fout:
                        output_filenames.append(output_filename)
                        writer = csv.writer(fout, reader, delimiter='^')
                        writer.writerow(fed_headers)
                        writer.writerows(chunk)
                            # print("Successfully converted into", output_file)
                return output_filenames

    paths = file_conversion(input_file,output_file+'{01}.csv',10000)
    # paths return a list of filenames that are created like output_file1.csv,output_file2.csv can be of any limit
    # when i tried paths[0], it returns output_file1.csv
    context = {'paths' :paths}

def test_download(request):
    paths = request.GET.get('paths')
    context ={'paths': paths}
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/zip')
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(response, 'w')
    for filename in paths:
        zip_file.write(filename)
    zip_file.close()
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='+'converted files'
    return response
```

templates

```
<p> 
<a href ="{% url 'test_download' %}?paths={{ paths|urlencode }} " download>Converted Files</a> </p>
<br>
```

Help me to find the issue here.

Issue:
[image]

the ?path is looking for file but it has found the list.

Then I tried:

```
def test_download(request):
    paths = request.GET.getlist('paths')
    context ={'paths': paths}
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/zip')
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(response, 'w')
    for filename in paths:
         zip_file.write(filename)
    zip_file.close()
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='+'converted files'
    return response
```

templates :

```
<p> <a href ="{% url 'test_download' %}?paths=path1 " download>Converted Files</a> </p>
<br>
```

It looks for the file as

```
FileNotFoundError at /test/
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/rikesh/Projects/FedMall/main/temp/47QSHA19D003A_UPDATE_20210113_{:01}.csv'
```

[image]

[image]

the file path should be :

```
/home/rikesh/Projects/FedMall/main/temp/47QSHA19D003A_UPDATE_20210113_0.csv
```

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace

Comment: I have edited it. The query set is looking for a file but it has found the list that contains the files. I actually want to zip them all and download.

Comment: I have included another stacktrace too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`request.GET.get('paths')` returns a string representation of your list of paths, not a list object. The returned value would be like this `"['/path/file1', 'path/file2']"`. When you iterate through paths, it actually iterates through each char in your string. That is why it first tries to find a directory with the name `[`.

To pass a list of file paths to a `GET` request, you would need to change your url to this

```
<your_url>?paths=path1&paths=path2&paths=path3...
```

In your Python code, get the file paths with this

```
request.GET.getlist('paths')
```

Comment: What if the number of paths in the list is not known?

Comment: Why do you need to know the number of paths? With each path, just append &paths=<your_path> to the end of your URL.

Comment: there can be as many files in the paths list. I need to zip them and make a download file.

Comment: Try changing your template to <a href ="{% url 'test_download' %}?{% for path in paths %}paths={{ path|urlencode }}&{% endfor %}">Converted Files</a>, see if it work

Comment: If there are lots of files in the paths, then the URL will be very long. Please refer to :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65839418/what-is-the-post-equivalent-for-requesting-get-parameters