# What is the alternative of passing array to the URL?(URL too long)

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, request

WHile requesting from GET  method, The url is created like

```
<your_url>?paths=path1&paths=path2&paths=path3...
```

This can be very long if there are large number of paths.

I want to request the paths through the POST method because the request lines are too large in the url created by the GET method. Is there any alternatives for

```
request.GET.getlist('paths')
```

if the paths are very long, then it shows Bad Request, Request Line too large.

There is an alternative for this:

```
request.POST.getlist('paths')
```

What will be the equivalent way to pass the data in the query string in the template so that the url will not be very long and all files can be downloaded?

views.py

```
def test_download(request):
    paths = request.GET.getlist('paths')
    context ={'paths': paths}
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/zip')
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(response, 'w')
    for filename in paths:
         zip_file.write(filename)
    zip_file.close()
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='+'converted files'
    return response
```

templates

```
<a href ="{% url 'test_download' %}?{% for path in paths %}paths={{ path|urlencode }}&{% endfor %}">Converted Files</a>
```

Comment: I feel you could design this better to include 1 path in the get request rather than multiple. That should ideally resolve the issue. On the Frontend, you can iterate over the paths and make GET calls for each path.

Comment: then the download links will be different, I have zipped the files from those paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a form instead of a hyperlink to submit a POST request and send your paths in POST data. See below for example code

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'test_download' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for path in paths %}
        <input type="hidden" name="paths" value="{{ path }}"
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Converted Files</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Do I need to create a separate form to store paths for this? When I clicked submit, It should download but it shows CSRF verification failed.

Comment: You need to add crsf token to your form. I forgot about it. Just edited the answer, added `{% csrf_token %}` to the form.

Comment: Hi Minh, please I need your help on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67156152/how-to-change-the-boolean-value-of-a-form-field-when-the-toggle-button-is-clicke